# Problemas con la funcion array_key_exists , no trae los datos

Tags: php, lista

Hola a todos amigos de esta comunidad, engo este código

```
$search_array = array('first' => 3, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "UNO";
}else if(array_key_exists('second', $search_array)){
    echo 'DOS';
}else{
    echo 'NADA';
}
```

y no me imprime el 'DOS', cual es el problema??

Comment: Pero el 'UNO' sí te lo imprime, verdad?

Comment: Porque siempre se está cumpliendo el primer `if`. Una vez entre a un `if`, `elseif` o `else` del mismo grupo condicional, ya no va a entrar a las demás condiciones de ese nivel.

Comment: SI, supongo que no imprime xq al cumplirse la primera opción se va del if

Comment: para que imprima UNO y DOS, no deberia tiener else if